# AWS Elastic Beanstalk [error] 2540#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting this error when trying to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk to connect to my Django code:

```
[error] 2540#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.63, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
```

My log is displayed below:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2020/12/21 03:43:19 [error] 2540#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.63, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:43:22 [error] 2540#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.14.160, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:43:34 [error] 2540#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.63, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:43:37 [error] 2540#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.14.160, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:43:49 [error] 2540#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.63, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:43:52 [error] 2540#0: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.14.160, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:44:04 [error] 2540#0: *13 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.63, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
2020/12/21 03:44:07 [error] 2540#0: *15 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.14.160, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.14.130"
```

Previously, I also received an error where it said

```
Dec 21 04:14:38 ip-172-31-14-130 web: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.14.130'. You may need to add '172.31.14.130' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Dec 21 04:14:38 ip-172-31-14-130 web: Bad Request: /
```

I did add 172.31.14.130 to the ALLOWED_HOSTS section of my settings.py file and then received the /var/log/nginx/error.log and when I try to access my webpage, it tells me the site took too long to respond - any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you ssh to your EB instance and `curl` your application from inside to confirm that it actually works?

Comment: @Marcin I don't have ssh setup for this instance yet but I could connect to the database and make tables via DBeaver, so I believe it is working

Comment: @ArshiaSharma did you ever fix it? I'm seeing the same issue leading to a 502 gateway error in every fresh django project I try to make

Comment: @AmanJha Yes, but I do believe the 502 gateway error is different than my issue; have you checked the log in elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 1):

You should use express to listen 8000 port since its try to listen http://127.0.0.1:8000/

```
const port = process.env.port || 8000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log(`listening on port ${port}....`)})
```

You can also set the port in AWS EB environment variable under configuration -> system -> Environment properties. Example below.

[image]